# How to fix "Dependency "switch" not found for preference "screen"

Tags: android

Dependency "switch" not found for preference "screen"

When I use ListPreference, everything works fine with android:dependency="switch" and also when I turn off android:dependency="switch" - I can open the PreferenceScreen.

But to unlock SwitchPreference and open the PreferenceScreen - gives an error.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dependency "switch" not found for preference "screen" (title: "Screen"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference
            android:title="Switch"
            android:key="switch"
            android:summaryOn="Description of switch 2 on"
            android:summaryOff="Description of switch 2 off"/>
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:dependency="switch"
            android:key="screen"
            android:summaryOn="Description of screen on"
            android:summaryOff="Description of screen off"
            android:title="Screen">
        <CheckBoxPreference
                android:summaryOn="Description of checkbox on"
                android:summaryOff="Description of checkbox off"
                android:title="CheckBox"
                android:key="checkbox"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem programmatically, but only xml does not work

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartScreenCallback {

        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.ex_003_preference, rootKey)
        }

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

            val switch = preferenceScreen.findPreference("switch") as SwitchPreference
            val screen = preferenceManager.findPreference("screen") as PreferenceScreen
            screen.isEnabled = false
            switch.isChecked = false
            switch.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                screen.isEnabled = switch.isChecked
                return@setOnPreferenceClickListener false
            }

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        }

        override fun onPreferenceStartScreen(preferenceFragmentCompat: PreferenceFragmentCompat?, preferenceScreen: PreferenceScreen?): Boolean {
            preferenceFragmentCompat?.preferenceScreen = preferenceScreen
            return true
        }

        override fun getCallbackFragment(): Fragment {
            return this
        }
```

}